# Retrieve values from C# code into NLog.config file

Tags: c#, nlog

Is it possible to use "variables" in the `NLog.config` configuration file to get values from some C# code ?

The reason I want to use a "variable" is to retrieve the password (that I use to log info in my database) previously entered by the user in a windows form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer:

I need to use the [Global Diagnostics Context](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/T_NLog_GlobalDiagnosticsContext.htm) class, like that:

- In the C# code, set the variable: `GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("myVariableName", "myValue");`
- In the NLog.config file, access to the variable : `${gdc:item=myVariableName}` gives me `"myValue"`